# Symfony2 Custom user provider doesn't works

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-security

I have a custom user provider, following the guide in:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/custom_provider.html

All is working without errors, but I don't manage to access the restricted zone.

In my `UserProvider` class, I set `$roles` var to have `array("ROLE_USER")` and that's the permission I need to access route app/list, but when I go to app/list, Symfony redirects me to login again and again.

I've seen the debug toolbar and it results:

```
Username    anon.
Authenticated?   yes
Roles   { }
Token class Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\AnonymousToken
```

My security.yml file is:

```yaml
security:
firewalls:
    secured_area:
        pattern:    ^/
        anonymous: ~
        form_login: ~
        http_basic:
            realm: "Secured Demo Area"
        form_login:
            provider: webservice
            login_path: login
            check_path: login_check
            always_use_default_target_path: true
            default_target_path: listado_actas
        logout:
            path:   logout
            target: login

role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]

access_control:
    - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }

providers:
    webservice:
        id: webservice_user_provider

encoders:
    Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext
    Actas\Gestion\UserBundle\Security\User\WebServiceUser:
        id: my.encoder.service
```

My `UserProvider` class looks like the following. I just call an XML service that gives me a TOKEN that I will store in my `UserClass`:

```
public function loadUserByUsername($username)
{
    $salt = "";
    $roles = "";
    // make a call to your webservice here

    $password = $this->request->get('_password');
    $xml_interface = new XMLInterfaceBundle();
    $token = $xml_interface->requestLogin($username, $password);

    if (strlen($token) > 10) {
        $roles = array("ROLE_USER");
        $salt  = "";
        return new WebserviceUser($username, $password, $salt, $roles, $token);
    }

    throw new UsernameNotFoundException(sprintf('Username "%s" does not exist.', $username));
}
```

This is my `UserObject` in `DaoAuthenticationProvider::checkAuthentication()`

```
Actas\Gestion\UserBundle\Security\User\WebserviceUser Object
(
    [username:Actas\Gestion\UserBundle\Security\User\WebserviceUser:private] => 44886706X
    [password:Actas\Gestion\UserBundle\Security\User\WebserviceUser:private] => 44886706XkCrDP
    [salt:Actas\Gestion\UserBundle\Security\User\WebserviceUser:private] => 
    [roles:Actas\Gestion\UserBundle\Security\User\WebserviceUser:private] => Array
        (
            [0] => ROLE_ADMIN
        )

    [my_token:Actas\Gestion\UserBundle\Security\User\WebserviceUser:private] => 
)
```

This is my routing.yml:

```yaml
xml_interface:
    resource: "@XMLInterfaceBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /

actas:
    resource: "@ActasBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /

login:
    pattern:   /login
    defaults:  { _controller: UserBundle:Default:login }

login_check:
    pattern:   /login_check

logout:
    pattern:   /logout
```

Comment: How did you set the `role_hierarchy` in `security.yml`?

Comment: I don't have it set, is it necessary?

Comment: Yes, I think so. I mentioned in my comment.

Comment: What version of Symfony 2 are you using?  login_check really should point to a named route.  I doubt if that is the problem though.

Comment: Been awhile since I have dug into a problem like this.  The form login process eventually ends up here: Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Provider\DaoAuthenticationProvider.  Might want to stick a die statement (or maybe a breakpoint) in the checkAuthentication method.  It could be that the password stuff is not right or you have some trivial error going on.

Comment: I've check checkAuthentication method and doesn't throw any exception. I've updated my question with user object.

Comment: I have a custom authentication encoder, and i have function isPassWordValid($encoded, $raw, $salt) { return true; } and that's what it returns. All seems fine, no errors, but still no User authenticated.

Comment: The 2.4 manual says that you MUST have routes defined for login_check.  http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html.  Fix that up and see if it helps.

Comment: I have it defined in routing.yml (see updated question) Is that what you mean?

Comment: In your security.yml file, check_path: /app/login_check should be check_path: login_check (drop the /app).  As should the rest of the routes.

Comment: I've changed security.yml and routing.yml, but still i don't user authenticated

Comment: Starting to run out of ideas.  After authentication the token is stored in the session.  The token is retrieved on subsequent request.  Need to make sure your token/user is properly serialized.  Maybe take a look at what UserProvider::refreshUser() is getting.

Comment: In UserAuthenticationProvider::authenticate() when i do 
$authenticatedToken->setAttributes($token->getAttributes()); the attributes of the token are empty, is that normal?

Answer (score 0):

Just try to set the `Role_hierarchy` as following:

```
security:
    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]
```

Don't forget to set the `role` of your `User` object as `ROLE_ADMIN`, for example, in order to match the `role_hierarchy`.

Comment: I've done it and it doesn't works... it redirects me to the login.

Comment: If I have a custom UserProvider, is it necessary to have a Custom Authorization or returning the WebserviceUser should be enough?

Comment: It's strange that it doesn't work. You need the custom authorization. Are you sure that you set the role of your `User` object as `ROLE_ADMIN`? If so, please update your question and I can verify whether you have done in the right way or not. One more thing, did you clear the cache?

Comment: I've checked that i'm returning WebserviceUser, i've seen that in the debug bar, it says that i'm authenticated anonymously, so I think the system is not recognizing my user, any help?

Comment: You can plugin your own UserProvider which only needs to return a user object.  So that is not the issue.  I'm assuming that your User and UserProvider both implement the required interfaces.

Comment: Yep, as it's written in official doc:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/custom_provider.html